# When do we use "redo", "do over" and "start over"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

It seems that British people often say "**redo**" and American people say "**do over**" and "**start over**".

There are some questions about these phrases I want to ask.

We say "**I do the test/ do the job/ do some work/ do some chores...**", then it makes more sense to say "**I redo the test/ redo the job/ redo some work/ redo some chores...**".

However, do we use "**redo**" with other kinds of action like "cook", "dance", "shoot" etc, for example, "**You haven't cooked/danced/shot… correctly. You need to redo it.**"?

We say "**redo the test**", but does it make sense to say "**do over the test**" or "**start over the test**"?

When do we use "**redo**", "**do over**" and "**start over**"?

Comment: More likely to say 'do the test over', or 'start the test over'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, we don't use  "do over" and "start over" in the UK, though if something has gone disastrously wrong we "start all over again," especially since Jerome Kern's "[Pick Yourself Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGUsRGuZb6k)" [1936].

Yes, we'd use **redo** for cook/dance/shoot, though in film we have the verb and noun "[reshoot](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reshoot)". And we *redo* a test, or "[resit](https://www.lexico.com/definition/resit)" it if it's like an exam. ("resit" can *also* be a noun.)

(The title of "[I do, I undo, I redo](https://www.theartnewspaper.com/2016/06/15/the-turbine-hall-how-the-tate-made-a-spectacle-of-itself)", by French-American artist Louise Bourgeois, would be be less assonant as "I do, I undo, I start over"!)

Comment: "That dance wasn't quite right; try it once again" would be more idiomatic than "Redo it."